# plotjuggler read rosbag error

Tags: ros, rosbag

when i run `run plotjuggler plotjuggler` to read data from a bag file, i encounter the following errors:

```
"libParserROS1.so" :  "Cannot load library /opt/ros/noetic/lib/plotjuggler/libParserROS1.so: (librosx_introspection.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)"
"libParserROS2.so" :  "Cannot load library /opt/ros/noetic/lib/plotjuggler/libParserROS2.so: (librosx_introspection.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)"
```

[image][image]

I have tried reinstalling plotjuggler, but the problems still exist. Can anyone tell me how to solve it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Looks like this was solved https://github.com/facontidavide/PlotJuggler/issues/901 - "This change should fix it, but you will need to wait for the release of 3.8.5"